# Flutter - Extraer item de un json

Tags: json, flutter, map

Buen día, necesito de vuestra valiosa ayuda...
Cómo puedo hacer para extraer un dato específico de un json dentro del ciclo de parseo del mismo.
En el ejemplo, necesito el dato LAT y LON de cada item del json con el fin de evaluar sus valores en otra función llamada mideDistancia()
Desde ya muchas gracias por su ayuda!

```
Future<List<Busqueda>> capturabusquedas(String comuna, String cert, String idRegion, String idComuna, String idEsp) async {
busquedas = [];
var res = await http.get(
    "https://www.xxxxxxx/Read.php?comuna=$comuna&cert=$cert&id_region=$idRegion&id_comuna=$idComuna&id_esp=$idEsp");
var jsonData = json.decode(res.body);
  if (this.mounted) {
    setState(() {
      for (var i in jsonData) {
        Busqueda busqueda = Busqueda(
          i["ID_PERSONA"],
          i["LAT"],
          i["LON"],
        );
        if (widget._sector) {
          if (jsonData["LAT"] != null) {
            var totalmts = mideDistancia(jsonData['LAT'], jsonData['LON']);
            if (totalmts <= 1000) {
              busquedas.add(busqueda);
            }
          }
        } else {
          busquedas.add(busqueda);
        }
      }
    });
  }
setState(() {
  registros = busquedas.length;
  _grabaBusqueda();
});
return busquedas;
```

}

Comment: te sale algún error o cual es el problema?

Comment: Si dentro del For intentas un print del valor en i["LAT"], te devuelve algo en consola?

Comment: @diegoveloper no aparece error, cuando hago debug no pasa por ahí, dado que no estoy tomando de buena forma el valor del item.

Comment: @tinoper intentando.... gracias!

Comment: Amigos, muchas gracias! el problema fue resuelto usando i['LAT], gracias @tinoper